# Can I migrate AWS elastic IP from a region to another region?

Tags: amazon-ec2, elastic-ip, aws-regions

Currently I am having t2-micro instance in Frankfurt(eu-ceentral-1). Now I want to migrate from this region to another i.e. Frankfurt-Mumbai. For that I am using AMI and Snapshot but it needs to create new instance which will use new elastic IP but I want to use same elastic IP which I am using in Frankfurt region. Is there a way I can do so???

Not getting solution for the same aws elastic IP migration from one region to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Elastic IP address is static; it does not change over time. An Elastic IP address is for use in a specific Region only, and cannot be moved to a different Region.

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#:~:text=An%20Elastic%20IP%20address%20is%20static%3B%20it%20does%20not%20change,moved%20to%20a%20different%20Region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#:%7E:text=An%20Elastic%20IP%20address%20is%20static%3B%20it%20does%20not%20change,moved%20to%20a%20different%20Region).